# Mosh using MobaXterm fails to connect with error, how to fix?

Tags: mobaxterm, mosh

I'm having a problem connecting to remote hosts using MobaXterm as my Mosh client.

I have no issues from Bash using my standard OpenSSh client to/from Slackware, Debian, and OpenBSD systems with the following command line:

```
mosh --ssh=\"ssh -p 50515\" -p 60050 username@hostname.sld.tld
```

When running a Windows client (MobaXterm), however, I get the following non-descript usage error, and I've configured the advanced settings in the MobaXterm Mosh session manager to reflect the UDP port I want to connect to on the mosh-server as well as the (TCP) SSH port - in this case, 50515.

The non-descript usage error I'm receiving back when trying to connect using MobaXterm is as follows:

```
/bin/moshsession usage:
  /bin/moshsession <server_name> <user_name> [<ssh_port_number> <locale> <Prediction_type> <mosh_server_command> <Mosh_ports_range> <Ssh_private_key>]
```

The command line I use in Bash or any other shell works fine, my firewall ports for UDP 60000-61000 are open, etc., But I can't figure out why I can't connect via MobaXterm. Using MobaXterm to connect using SSH itself is no problem.

What am I doing wrong? Or what might I try to correct this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone still has this problem...
I had to *Allow a blocked (MobaXterm) app in Windows Security*

> 1. Select Start  > Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection.
> 2. Under Virus & threat protection settings, select Manage settings.
> 3. Under Controlled folder access, select Manage Controlled folder access.

After allowing all MobaXterm folder permissions it worked